# How to use Service to update sqlite database in android

Tags: android, sqlite, android-service

I am able to update sqlite database and retrieving the data through a thread from my Activity. But i need to update the database using Service, which will update the database in every 5 minute, whether my Application running or not. So when i run the application, i will get data from current database. 
I am stuck while writing Service to update the database.Can someone guide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a timer object on your service class
`Timer timer=new Timer();` 
On on create

```
@Override
public void onCreate()
{
    super.onCreate();
    timer.schedule(new DelayedTask(),300, 300000);// 300000 is 5min

}
```

Class DelayedTask

```
private class DelayedTask extends TimerTask
{

    @Override
    public void run() {
        Log.i(tag,"Timer Task executing");

        // code for updating sqlite database


    }

}
```

Comment: `ScheduledExecutorService` is generally preferred over `TimerTask` and this does not address the problem that Android can stop a service at any time.  If that happens, the scheduled tasks will not execute.

Answer (score 0):

This question if very general.  To see how to use a service, take at look at [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html).

If you want your service to be woken every five minutes, you should use the [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html).

If you have a specific question along the way, post that.

Comment: My service keeps on consuming more memory. At some point it reached almost 30 MB. Eventually service is closed by the ActivityManager and statement issued is:Force stopping service ServiceRecord
Why service consumes so memory,but the App ran in just 100KB or so.