# Optimize Android database update (SQLite) from web service

Tags: android, database, json, sqlite

Good day.

I've constructed an app that has an `SQLite` database that retrieves its contents from a `JSON` service pre-populated using `MySQL`. Every day, there is an update, a minor name change or insert, and I'm still unsure on how to implement the local `SQLite` database update.

So... my problem is, how do I optimize the update of my app's database wherein (if not real-time) it can check for database changes and updates every 2 minutes or so if there is a change, perform a background check for updates and insert (or update) the new content instead of just clearing out the previous local database and repopulate it again.

Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: is it one way replication (there is no changed on local SQLite)?

Comment: Yes, it is one way.

The only thing that changes is the MySQL database, serves to JSON, then retrieved by the local SQLite database and updates.

Comment: if so ... first add timestamp column to all tables and update it with current time at the time when you updating row (im talking about server side database) then let android send last time when it run replication and server side let give only this rows that were changed(thats why you need those timestamp column) ... do not update it every X minutes .. use GCM to send info to android device when data changed ..

Comment: Is there another way other than using time stamps? I can't edit the server-sided database. :(

Comment: You need *some* attribute to detect records that are new. If the server DB doesn't have this, you have to check all records every time.

Comment: Checking all the records would be fine.
I was thinking of just parsing the JSON data and comparing it to the pre-populated SQLite database. If there's a change, I'll retrieve the change and update its row on the local SQLite database.

But due to my limited Android (newbie here) knowledge, I'm stuck and stumped on how to do it. I've been Google-ing on how to compare parsed JSON data to SQLite database, but to no luck, I've found none. :(

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :
Just make one DBHandler class and write one function to insert the items into that table with necessary parameters. and one delete method to delete all previous records from table.

Whenever you get a updated data then reinsert all data into that table.

This is one of the solution that i am currently using.

check this : [To update table for every 2 minutes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7721800/how-to-use-service-to-update-sqlite-database-in-android)